# when i pass java object to client side i get " 406 not acceptable"

Tags: javascript, http-headers, client-side, content-type, http-status-code-406

I get " 406 not acceptable". I read somewhere they mentioned "we can give content-type in HTTP Header".

```
method: 'POST',
url: url,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

Like this, what are the values we can give to content-type?

Answer (score 0):

**Content Type**

Content Type is also known as MIME (Multipurpose internet Mail Extension) Type. It is a HTTP header that provides the description about what are you sending to the browser.

There are many content types:

```
text/html
text/plain
application/msword
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/jar
application/pdf
application/octet-stream
application/x-zip
images/jpeg
video/quicktime
```

etc.